# Как работает выделение текста\блоков в safary?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, safari

Если у вас есть опыт работы с выделением текста\блока или других элементов в safary, прошу обьясните основы того как оно работает. В плане того, почему при 3-м клике по элементу выделяется он и его сосед, а не только он. Или почему при двойном нажатии на пустое пространство внутри блока, в одном случае выделяется только текст внутри этого блока, а в другом весь блок.

Comment: если для елемента  в css назначить  user-select: none; то внутри него вообще ничего не будет выделяться, и при тройном клике выделиться весь блок у которого такое свойство не назначено..